# Facebook tab iframe sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-iframe

i have a tab in a page, with an iframe to a site built up to be like a simple facebook app, where users can create simple profile pages with an image and some text.

Now, once the profile is created (which is a simple html page with its own URL), i need to be able to share it, using some sharing services (like addthis) or even the standard send button. The problem is that the original site has to be always hidden (users have to not be able to see the URL of the "site"), but the sharing system need an absolute URL to know... what to actually share.

Obiouvsly, working in an iframe, the url is always that of the facebook page (it doesn't change navigating the site's pages), so how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the original site has to be always hidden (users have to not be able to see the URL of the "site")

Why not?

Please don’t say “security concerns” right now, because you should know there is no such thing as “security by obscurity” …

---

If you just want to have Open Graph URLs, that can be liked and shared, but want the user clicking on one of those URLs end up being in your iframe tab on Facebook again – then do a redirect to your page tab for actual users.

Either do it via JavaScript (which the Facebook scraper does not care about); or with a server-side redirect for any client that is *not* the Facebook scraper (it’s identifiable by it’s user agent or originating IP address of the request).

Comment: Well, it's simply because "the client want things done this way" (i know, it sucks). Anyway, thanks for the reply, luckily we found another route so that's not a problem anymore... for now. Thanks again!